# Make a link appears on a page only if the visitor is one of my subscribers?

Tags: html, youtube, subscribe

I wonder if there is any way to, on a page of my website, show a link or a div only if the visitor subscribed to my channel, with api's or something ? I already saw something like this with facebook in the past but now i'd like to use this kind of thing. Is it possible in any kind of way ?

Comment: login cookie maybe? i suppose you going to use javascript to perform ajax request to get the link, so at server only respond link if login found

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this in many ways depending on how are you checking witherthe user is a subscriber or not

if you store this in a bool value then all you need is a bit of javascript

```
<html>
body>
<a href ="#" class = "hidden"/>
</body> 

$(function(){
var isSubscribed = //Here the value;
if(isSubscribed )
{
$(a).removeClass('hidden');
}
})
```

if you are using any server side language then it will be far easier